# Why am I not able to see other user's markers which are stored on RTDB Firebase on Google Map Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

The issue is that I can only see my own marker on Google Maps while not of other users even tho the other users data (i.e. Latitude & Longitude) are stored on Realtime Database.

Below you can see the code:

```
final DatabaseReference _locationRef =
      FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('user_locations/$uid');

// For fetching icon from Firebase Storage
getIcons() async {
    Reference referenceRoot =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('img/profile_pictures/$uid');
    var imageUrl = await referenceRoot.getDownloadURL();
    try {
      final Uint8List markerImageBytes = await DefaultCacheManager()
          .getSingleFile(imageUrl)
          .then((file) => file.readAsBytes());
      final ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(markerImageBytes,
          targetWidth: 100, targetHeight: 100);
      final ByteData? byteData = await codec.getNextFrame().then((frameInfo) =>
          frameInfo.image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png));
      return BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(byteData!.buffer.asUint8List());
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error on getting icon: $e');
    }
  }

// Saving user location
void saveUserLocation() async {
    try {
      await _locationRef.set({
        "latitude": _currentPosition!.latitude.toString(),
        "longitude": _currentPosition!.longitude.toString()
      });
      print("Database Written in real-time");
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error writting user location: $e"); //
    }
  }
 void updateUserLocation() async {
    try {
      await _locationRef.update({
        "latitude": _currentPosition!.latitude.toString(),
        "longitude": _currentPosition!.longitude.toString()
      });
      print("Database Updated in real-time");
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error updating user location: $e"); //
    }
  }

  void getLocation() async {
    Geolocator.getPositionStream(
      locationSettings: const LocationSettings(
        accuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation,
      ),
    ).listen((position) {
      setState(() {
        _currentPosition = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
        saveUserLocation();
        _createMarker();
      });
    });
  }

  // Function for creating marker
  Future<Set<Marker>> _createMarker() async {
    final icon = await getIcons();
    if (_currentPosition != null && icon != null) {
      Marker userMarker;
      _locationRef.onValue.listen((event) {
        Map<dynamic, dynamic> userLocation =
            event.snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
        userLocation.forEach((key, value) {
          double? latitude = double.tryParse(userLocation['latitude'] ?? '');
          double? longitude = double.tryParse(userLocation['longitude'] ?? '');
          if (latitude != null && longitude != null) {
            userMarker = Marker(
              markerId: MarkerId(uid!),
              position: LatLng(latitude, longitude),
              icon: icon,
              infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                title: "$username",
                snippet: "$username's Location",
              ),
            );
            setState(() {
              marker.clear();
              marker.add(userMarker);
            });
          } else {
            print('Invalid latlng for user with key: $key');
          }
        });
      });
    }

    return marker;
  }

  void _initMapAndMarkers() async {
    final markers = await _createMarker();
    setState(() {
      _markers = markers; // Assuming _markers is a Set<Marker> in your state
    });
  }

  GoogleMap(
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              zoomControlsEnabled: true,
              initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                target: _currentPosition ?? const LatLng(0, 0),
              ),
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                if (!_googleMapController.isCompleted) {
                  _googleMapController.complete(controller);
                }
              },
              markers: Set<Marker>.of(_markers),
            ),
```

I was trying to get all other users marker (i.e. That every user can see each other location through map).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `_locationRef` points to the data for a specific user, and that seems to be the only path you read from the database.

If you want to read data from all UID values, read from one level higher and loop over the results, as shown in the documentation on [listening for a list of values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events).

Comment: can you provide a bit of hint on how can I do that?

Comment: Your code already creates a database reference to `'user_locations/$uid'`. If you store the location for all users in that way, you'll want to create a reference to `'user_locations'` and read that in a way similar to the documentation I linked.

Comment: oh alright I will try the method and if works I will accept the answer